# Read File Directory and enter Files into SQL Table Log but only New Files

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

Im trying to use the xp_cmdshell to read a file directory then paste those file names into a log table.  Everytime I read the directory I just want to add the new file to the log table. Below is what I have right now but its messy.

```
Declare @FileName Table(FileList Varchar(255))
Insert Into @FileName  
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'dir "C:\Data Log\EODFiles\*.CSV" /b'
Declare @FilePath Varchar(255)
Select Top 1 FilePath= FileList 
FROM [dbo].[EOD_Log] 
right join  @FileName 
on filelist = File_log
where filelist is NOT NULL  and File_log is NULL 
Insert Into  [dbo].[EOD_Log] (File_log)
select @filepath from @FileName where @filepath is not NULL
```

Comment: The code queries the data I need correctly but its not inserting it into the eod_log table.

Comment: @FilePath2 is never used. The SELECT results are not used (why not insert them into the table directly).

Comment: sorry that should be @filepath not filepath2.  I have a procedure before this to identify anything not in my EOD_log table that is currently in the directory.  It then loads the file that is not in the EOD_Log.  After that file has been loaded I want that file name to be added to the EOD_log.  This is that part of the procedure.  But I cant get it to insert.  Could you help me with the statement to insert directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @FileName Table(FileList Varchar(255))

INSERT INTO @FileName  
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'dir "C:\Data Log\EODFiles\*.CSV" /b'

INSERT INTO  [dbo].[EOD_Log] (filename)
SELECT FileList From @FileName 
WHERE Filelist NOT IN (select * FROM [dbo].[EOD_Log])  
ORDER BY filelist desc
```

This should solve your NULLs problem, instead of having a variable to be left empty when there are no rows in an assignment it will simply do no INSERTs.  Why even use the Top 1?  And I think you don't even need to check for NULLs in FileList column.

Comment: Thank you! I select top one because I have a BCP procedure to import the data that isnt in my log and the bcp script I have will only allow for one file name.  I just have the standard edition of SQL so I dont have SQL Management for the SSIS Packages.  Its a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work but its still messy.

```
DECLARE @FileName Table(FileList Varchar(255))
INSERT INTO @FileName  
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'dir "C:\Data Log\EODFiles\*.CSV" /b'
DECLARE @FilePath Varchar(255)
SELECT Top 1 @FilePath= FileList From @FileName 
WHERE FileList is Not Null and Filelist NOT IN (select * FROM [dbo].[EOD_Log])  
ORDER BY filelist desc
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[EOD_Log] (filename)
VALUES (@filepath)
DELETE from [dbo].[EOD_Log]
WHERE filename IS NULL
```